# Numerical evaluation of large number of constraints in nminimize at each step

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with complicated constraints which can be computed only numerically. I have written a module that computes lhs of these constraints. Now I need to tell Mathematica that each of these constraints must be less than or equal to 0. I tried using Thread command inside `NMinimize`, However, Mathematica evaluates thread first and returns an error while substituting numbers. I tried `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` within `NMinimize` as illustrated in other posts, but it did not work out.

I have included a simple and trivial example here. Nevertheless it points to my question,

```
const[x_?NumericQ] := Module[{ret},
ret = {f[x], f[2*x], f[3*x]};
Return[ret];]
```

The optimization part

```
NMinimize[x^2, Thread[const[x] <= 4], {x}]
```

Returns error:

> NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {const[x]<=4}.
>   Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables

Comment: Try `NMinimize[Flatten@{x^2, Thread[const[x] <= 4]}, {x}]` instead. In the presence of constraints, NMinimize requires a flat list of equations and constraints as its first argument (see third syntax example [in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the pattern `x_?NumericQ` when defining `const`, because you are not using it numerically but symbolically.

```
f[x_] := 42 + x
const[x_] := {f[x], f[2*x], f[3*x]}
NMinimize[x^2, Thread[const[x] <= 4], {x}]
```

> `{1444., {x -> -38.}}`

Note that I have removed a lot of unnecessary code from your definition of `const`.

Comment: but in my actual problem I cannot evaluate the constraints analytically because it is too complicated. How can I do this numerically?

Comment: The constraints in the original problem cannot be evaluated symbolically, that is why I have used NumericQ in this example. Is it possible to do this numerically and return a result that NMinimize will be able to interpret?